# Window Function Issue with Results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

My CASE Statement is not working, it's not outputting the expected result.

Current Results:

[image]

I want the person with the lowest amount of MondayHours to = 1 and so on.  If null, then ignore in the window function.

Expected results:
[image]

I only need one CASE statement, I've put in a couple I've been working with. If the MondayHours is null, then they need to be ignored in the count.  How can I get my expected results (above) with a CASE statement, please?

Sample code for testing:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t1

CREATE TABLE #t1 ( EmpID VARCHAR(36), [IsMonday] bit, IsTuesday bit, IsWednesday bit, IsThursday bit, [MondayHours] decimal(9,2), TuesdayHours decimal(9,2), WednesdayHours decimal(9,2), ThursdayHours decimal(9,2), [LastName] varchar(30), [FirstName] varchar(30) )

INSERT INTO #t1 (EmpID, [IsMonday], IsTuesday, IsWednesday, IsThursday, [MondayHours], TuesdayHours, WednesdayHours, ThursdayHours, [LastName], [FirstName])
VALUES
( 'FDD12035-792D-4C53-80F1-AT28065A0968', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0.00, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SMITH', 'JOHN' ),
( 'B9968A1F-0203-4A69-EW14-366A05BC2B2E', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1.50, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'HIGHTOWER', 'OFFICER' ),
( 'FDD12035-792D-4C53-80F1-AT28065A0968', NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 18.50, NULL, 'SMITH', 'JOHN' ),
( 'FDD12035-792D-4C53-80F1-AT28065A0968', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0.00, 'SMITH', 'JOHN' )



SELECT empid
, CASE WHEN IsMonday IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE Dense_Rank()OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID  ORDER BY MondayHours, LastName, FirstName) END AS MondayHours_DenseRank_1
, CASE WHEN IsMonday IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE Dense_Rank()OVER( ORDER BY MondayHours, LastName, FirstName) END AS MondayHours_DenseRank_2
, IsMonday
, MondayHours
, LastName
, FirstName
FROM #T1
```

Comment: Are you sure you are expecting `1,2`?   (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/l14OIcNL, which gives `1,1` )

Comment: Ok, see this one: https://dbfiddle.uk/NiB6zkG3 (Please do not ask for explanation, I just played with the `PARTITION BY`  and `ORDER BY.....` )

Comment: Ha! Lol, that's funny. (I fixed it, but don't look at it.) Good job. I thought about trying a negative, but I wasn't sure how it would work, or in this case, is working.  Can anyone else explain how the negative is working?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I will try:

```
SELECT empid
, CASE WHEN IsMonday IS NULL 
       THEN NULL 
       ELSE Dense_Rank()OVER(ORDER BY MondayHours, LastName, FirstName)-1
       END AS MondayHours_DenseRank_1
, Dense_Rank()OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID  ORDER BY MondayHours, LastName, FirstName) mdr_test
, CASE WHEN IsMonday IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE Dense_Rank()OVER( ORDER BY MondayHours, LastName, FirstName) END AS MondayHours_DenseRank_2
, IsMonday
, MondayHours
, LastName
, FirstName
FROM #T1
ORDER BY MondayHours
```

output:

| empid | MondayHours_DenseRank_1 | mdr_test | MondayHours_DenseRank_2 | IsMonday | MondayHours | LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FDD12035-792D-4C53-80F1-AT28065A0968 | null | 1 | null | null | null | SMITH | JOHN |
| FDD12035-792D-4C53-80F1-AT28065A0968 | null | 1 | null | null | null | SMITH | JOHN |
| FDD12035-792D-4C53-80F1-AT28065A0968 | 1 | 2 | 2 | True | 0.00 | SMITH | JOHN |
| B9968A1F-0203-4A69-EW14-366A05BC2B2E | 2 | 1 | 3 | True | 1.50 | HIGHTOWER | OFFICER |

- I added the column `mdr_test` with the DENSE_RAND, but without the CASE WHEN.
- The first two lines get value 1,

  - then 2 because of the change in `MondayHours`
  - then 1 again because of the partition by `EmpID`

When changing that to: `Dense_Rank()OVER(ORDER BY -MondayHours desc, LastName, FirstName) mdr_test`

- The first two line will the be `MondayHours`=0 from SMITH
- The second line will be the `MondaysHours`=1.5, followed by the two lines with a NULL value.

The behaviour is explained by the `DENSE_RANK()` also counting the row that you exclude by using the `CASE WHEN...END` construction.